# How to remove a stored user name and password in Wifi Connection Settings?

Tags: wi-fi, password

I've cleared all stored WiFi connections but the password prompt seen in the screenshot still appears. That user name and password is actually part of a VPN connection I had. I've deleted that VPN connection too. The prompt persists. How can I remove that stored user name and password?

Pixel 2 Android 8.0.0.
Security patch level: November 5, 2017.

[image: Wifi Settings]

Comment: Did you use some app that saves passwords? Because i haven't seen the phone saving passwords on it's own

Comment: also try clearing your settings cache and other caches. may be reboot after cache clearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `Autofill service` from `Autofill with Google` to `None`.

[image: Autofill service screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

For me that seems like another third party application is rendering the UI (drawing over your settings app) for saved WiFi passwords since natively, forgetting a WiFi will delete and forget it's password and manual settings too. Go to settings, Apps:

[image: App Settings]

and click the cogwheel icon on the top right corner,

[image: configure apps]

click drawing over other apps.

[image: Draw over other Apps]

Disable all apps. Return to you WiFi settings if it doesn't show, enable them one by one to note which application was doing that. Hope this helps you

Comment: It wasn't this. I disabled all apps listed under "Display over the other apps" except for "System UI" which can not be disabled. Prompt still appears. Thanks for the suggestion I would not have thought to try this. ☮

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your appreciation. Until someone comes with an alternative.